# Couldn't create Solr Repository using Spring Data Solr

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, solr

I couldn't create Spring Solr Repository.

Below is my bean configuration

```
<context:annotation-config />

<solr:solr-server id="solrServer" url="http://soms-env.staples.com:8983/solr" />

<bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
</bean>

<bean id="searchRepository"
    class="com.solr.repository.SolrCurrencyRepository">
    <property name="solrOperations" ref="solrTemplate" />
</bean>
```

and the code used in my controller is

```
@Autowired
private SolrCurrencyRepository searchRepository;
```

Getting below error all the time.

SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.solr.repository.SolrCurrencyRepository Controller.MainController.searchRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.solr.repository.SolrCurrencyRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)

Am I missing anything to instantiate Repository.

Comment: Can you share SolrCurrencyRepository code?

Comment: This is resolved now.. Thanks for your response. I made a mistake in updating the bean config in Target spring config file, it was supposed to be updated in application. this had occurred since I opened many versions of the config file. Thanks!!